# dd behavior, default writing and partitions

Tags: partition, dd

I am confused about the behavior of dd.

Say we have some SD card called `/dev/foo` and this card has partitions `/dev/foop0` and `/dev/foop1`. Using dd, I can set the `of` argument to `/dev/foo` and `dd` won't complain. But what exactly will happen? Will `dd` just write to the first partition? Or will it overwrite both partitions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dd` will write at the start of the disk itself, overwriting the partition table in the process.

You'll have trashed all the data on that disk (would need recovery software and luck to recover, depending on how much you wrote).

Note that this behavior isn't specific to `dd`, you'd see the same thing with `cat` or anything else. If you write to `/dev/foo`, you overwrite the whole disk starting with the partition table.

Comment: So dd just steamrolls everything? Is there a way to do dd on specific partitions?

Comment: `dd` just writes bytes where you tell it to, it doesn't care if that's a disk, a file, a partition or a lava lamp. Use `/dev/foopX` to write to the partition. Use great caution though, there's no safety belt if you're root.

Comment: Poor lava lamp...